# regex to match entire words containing (one or more) mandatory and allowed characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to match entire words that containing **at least one of** mandatory chars and allowed chars.

For example
Mandatory chars are : [ t , a , x ]
Allowed chars are : [ i , e]

```
t     : passed (one of mandatories are here)
tea   : passed (two of mandatories(t,a) and one allowed(e) here)
e     : failed (none of mandatory is here)
teas  : failed (two of mandatories(t,a) and one allowed(e) here but one intruder(s))
```

What is the appropriate REGEX code for this?
It will be used for search 12.000 rows of MySQL table containing one word each row as a PHP project.

Comment: Do you need to be able to capture which mandatory and which allowed characters were seen, as well as what "intruders" there are?

Comment: No, I only need to check if it passed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\b[ie]*+[taxie]++\b
```

explanation:

since `[ie]*+` has a word boundary on the left and a possessive quantifier, it grab all `i` and `e` as possible and will never give them back, then the next character must be a `t`, an `a` or an `x` from the next class with the + quantifier that impose at least 1 character.

The word boundary on the right disallow other kind of characters.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: it can't, read the explanation to understand why.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than giving a straight answer, let me help you help yourself. A word that passes consists of a sequence of:

- zero or more allowed or mandatory characters
- a mandatory character
- zero or more allowed or mandatory characters

Write regexes for each of these, then just concatenate them to get a regex for the entire thing.

Comment: And make sure to include either word boundaries on either end, or start/end string markers, to make sure you don't match things like `teas` where `tea` matches but the s at the end fails.

Comment: Right, I was assuming a regex "match"/"test" function, with implicit anchors.

Answer (score 0):

In perl it would be..

`$string =~ /^[tax]*[ie]+$/i; #i is for ignore case`

* is a 1 or more + is a 0 or more

I just realized you wanted entire words hold on let me rewrite it..

the ^ and $ will match start and end of line.